# ng-click function behavior when we use dot in the name

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularJS, How to configure the ng-click="reviewCtrl.submit()" function?

```js
 
 $scope.reviewCtr.submit= function(){
    alert("this is alert");
  };
```

```html
 <button id="submitBtn" tabindex="50"  type="button" ng-click="reviewCtrl.submit()" >Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reviewCtrl` is a reference to [controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) instance known as controller-as syntax. In order to use it you would need to use this notation in HTML:

```
ng-controller="YourController as reviewCtrl"
```

and attache `submit` function to controller instead of $scope object:

```
.controller('YourController', function () {
  this.submit = function () {
    alert("this is alert")
  }
})
```